# How to make switch case syntax smaller?

Tags: c#

i'm making simple name generator, and it's working like that: I got an array with name values it's 4 elements, and i'm using random class to pick specific name from array, and next i'm using switch case to validate which one is picked and print it to console.

But, it's only 4 element, but what when i'll try to make 100 elements 4example? I've tried to make switch case in for loop to increment everything in one case, but it turns out that case index should be const. Well, is there any other possible way to make switch case more flexible, and smaller?

Here's code for intersed http://pastebin.com/bbCxLtRq

Comment: Post your code, not a link to your code.

Comment: Why don't you use the random number directly to index the array?

Comment: Oh dear, so many kittens killed...

Comment: Shameless plug... an old name generator (for Spanish names) I posted on Github a while ago (this was just for testing github really ;-) ): https://github.com/javiercampos/GeneradorNombres . Code and name dataset are in Spanish but should be easy enough to follow :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your methods independents of a fixed length:

```
public static string NameGen()
{
    int index = random.Next(Names.Length);
    return Names[index];
}

public static string SurnameGen()
{
    int index = random.Next(Surnames.Length);
    return Surnames[index];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `switch` needed:

```
if (NameIndex >= 0 && NameIndex <= 3)
{
    return Name[NameIndex];
}
return null;
```

With more complex examples, you can use `return` to get rid of `break`.

Instead of

```
    switch (NameIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                name = Name[0];
            break;

            case 1:
                name = Name[1];
            break;

            case 2:
                name = Name[2];
            break;

            case 3:
                name = Name[3];
            break;
        }
        return name;
```

write

```
    switch (NameIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                return Name[0];

            case 1:
                return Name[1];

            case 2:
                return Name[2];

            case 3:
                return Name[3];
        }
    return null;
```

Comment: I would put the "or just" at the top of your answer, _then_ offer alternatives.  It's so simple and short it's easy to overlook.

Comment: @DStanley the question was about switch .. case statement though.

Comment: Actually that second example would not compile as it doesn't have a return for the default case and the last one has a similar problem because the return is in an `if`.

Comment: @juharr third example returns no default value as well. I should add it for clarification

Comment: @enkryptor You could just add a `return null;` to the end of both.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is NO need for `Switch` statement to achieve this goal - refer to the following code snippet as an example:

```
public class Generate
{
    static string[] Name = new string[] { "Mariusz", "Janusz", "Bogdan", "Zbigniew" };
    static Random random = new Random();

    public static string NameGen()
    {
      return Name[(int) random.Next(3)];
    }
}
```

In case you really need to use `Switch` statement (for some reason, may be just for didactic purpose), then there is a way to simplify it like shown in the following snippet:

```
switch (NameIndex)
        {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                return Name[NameIndex];
        }
```

Hope this may help